# Running a JavaScript as an external script in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a blade code like this:

```html
<input type='text' id="input1">
<div >
 <h3 id="showData"> Data will be shown here  </h3>

</div>

<script>
  var input=document.getElementById('input1').value;

  document.getElementById('showData').innerHTML=input;
</script>
```

What I want is to write the script part in a separate file (say called externalScript.js) and call it here in the blade file.

Also, I have a doubt about it. If I do that, since the script is run from an external file, how will it fetch the `id` values like `input1` or `showData` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a new file called: `externalScript1.js`

Add the script tag, best in the head or foot part of your code.

```
    <script src="{{ asset('externalScript1.js') }}" defer></script>
```

(the asset helper gets the path to the public folder, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset)

In the end everything will load from one page, ergo the elements are found, so you won't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to use the same script everywhere, now, all I need to do is use the source

Answer (score 2):

Just add js file in laravel resources directory, link to webpack and compile [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vendor-extraction).

when it comes to executing the script, attach it at the end of the page (before `</body>`) or wait for the page to be loaded `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {})`

Attach the js file in the main wrapper, not in the nested blade element